# Highlight a magnitude circle in a compass diagram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using compass diagrams in *Matlab*.
I need to highlight a magnitude level (so a circle centered in the origin of the *compass* diagram) in order to put emphasis on those vectors exceeding such magnitude. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

#### Example

My compass diagrams is quite simple, I just follow the methodology shown [here](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/creating_plots/direction-and-velocity-vector-graphs.html#f10-1352) in order to convert some polar coordinates into cartesian ones. In my case I display wind strength and direction (very similar to the example provided my *Mathworks*):

```
wdir = [31.45 21.45 44.67 23.87];
knots = [7.2 4.4 5.3 6.6];
rdir = wdir * pi/180;
[x,y] = pol2cart(rdir,knots);
compass(x,y)
```

I need to highlight the **4.0 knots** level because when the wind exceeds this intensity, something important happens. If you look the screenshot I took a while ago (which is the *compass* diagram coming out from the code I wrote before):

[image]

What I want is to highlight the grey circle dotted line which indicates the magnitude 4. That's all!

#### PS

Please note that I do not want to highlight the vectors, but I just want to draw a circle corresponding to a certain magnitude in the diagram. That's all.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to generate your compass - it should be relatively easy to add a few commands that draw a circle. What have you tried?

Comment: I added the code, which is quite similar to the one provided by Mathworks in their examples.

Comment: Can you show what happened when you added my code? It ought to plot right over your compass, but you say it doesn't. What does it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comments, I found a machine to test my code on.

Here is the exact code I used:

```
wdir = [31 24 44 23];
knots = [7 4 5 6];
rdir = wdir * pi/180;
[x,y] = pol2cart(rdir, knots);
figure
compass(x,y);

hold on;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
kLimit = 4.0;
xt = kLimit * cos(theta);
yt = kLimit * sin(theta);
plot(xt, yt, 'r')
```

This is the output I got:

[image]

I'm not sure why it wasn't working for you. I think this is what you were asking for. Can you see if this exact code works for you? And if I still misunderstand, please explain?

Comment: Gonna try this in few hours, thanks in advance anyway! I'll let you know soon!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I want to get! I just want to act on the same figure the compass command creates and highlight one level. I think I need to take a screenshot of this... Gonna edit my post soon. Thanks anyway for your hard work :)

Comment: Look forward to the screenshot. Looks like it may take a bit of hands on time to solve...